# Flex progress loading disappear?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, progress-bar

It looks like strange occurrence - te progressbar whcih shows the progress of loading the flex application all of the sudden disappear.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Without details, this risks to be closed as not real question...

Comment: I dont know what causing it ... When i start a clean project, i have the progress bar, but later it gone..

Comment: Maybe it just finished loading? :)

Comment: intantly ... idk ... the swf is about 2 mb ... something is not as it should .. i were hoping that someone had the simirar occurances. (Flex 4.5 btw)

Comment: browser caching will essentially remove the progress bar since it doesn't really load anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you were right @J_A_X and @alxx - it came back when i clean the history and temp files and etc ...
It was very strange occurance...

Thank you.